# Failure to pass WCF DataMembers

Tags: c#, wcf

Problem: Some but not all datamembers in a WCF datacontract class are failing to pass properly.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICheckList
{
    [OperationContract]
    int UpsertManager(ManagerEntity newObj);
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class ManagerEntity
{
    [DataMember] public bool TrainingComplete{get;set;}
    [DataMember] public int IsPosted{get;set;}
    [DataMember] public DateTime TrainingDate{get;set;}
    [DataMember] public string Comments{get;set;}
}
```

Client side code:

```
BRTWSLChecklist.ManagerEntity newModel = new BRTWSLChecklist.ManagerEntity();
newModel.TrainingComplete = model.HasTrainingDate;
newModel.Comments = model.Comments;
newModel.IsPosted = 1;
newModel.TrainingDate = DateTime.Today;

ChecklistClient.UpsertManager(newModel);
```

WCF Side:

```
public int UpsertManager(ManagerEntity newObj)
{
    bool t = newObj.TrainingComplete;   //always false
    DateTime x = newObj.TrainingDate;   //always equal to 1/1/0001
    string c = newObj.Comments;         //no problems here 
    int d = newObj.IsPosted;            //no problems here
}
```

Any ideas why two out of four are ok, but the bools and datetimes are failing??

Comment: Does your client side code have properties `TrainingCompleteSpecified` and `TrainingDateSpecified`? If so: you must set those to **true** when you've specified some values for those properties ....

Comment: Please explain why and how I would add such things. I'm somewhat new to wcf and have not encountered that in any tutorials

Comment: After browsing the intellisense I found some properties for which there was created an "Specified" version in addition to the original property. When set to true the related property was binding correctly.

Comment: Remove the `[Serializable]` attribute - that may be the source of the `Specified` version of properties.  The `[DataContract]` attribute will serialize the object (with the `DataContractSerializer`) so it can be sent across the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your client side code have properties `TrainingCompleteSpecified` and `TrainingDateSpecified`?

If so: you must set those to true when you've specified some values for those properties...

For some types of properties, WCF cannot distinguish between you having not specified any value, or you having specified a value that also can look like "nothing". Therefore, for these kinds of properties, the WCF client-side runtime adds the `bool (property)Specified` properties into your client-side code; if you want to pass a value to the server, these `(property)Specified` properties **must be set** to `true` - otherwise, your values set will be ignored / not seen on the server side.

Comment: Is that true for the DataContractSerializer?  I haven't seen that in the WCF services I've built, but I've seen it in older or non-.NET services I've worked with.

Comment: You were correct and I marked your answer as such. It appears that there is two ways of going about it. 1) to set the correlated (property)Specified attribute to true 2) you can use [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] instead of just [DataMember]. I went with the second option as it required less coding on my part. Thanks again for your help,